# Posting JSON data as Params in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have JSON data that I need to **post** to an API endpoint *as a parameter*. How can I do this in **Angular** using **HttpClient**?

```js
export class resultService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  
  listResult() {
    const options = {
      "city": "value1",
      "id": 12,
      "c": null
    };
    
    //I need to call this API end point with POST method
    //http://someapi.com/fetch?id={"city": "value1", "id": 12, "c": null}
    return this.http.post('http://someapi.com/fetch', null, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }),
      params: {"id": options}
      //Options can't be passed here cz params doesn't accept JSON type
    })
  }
  
    
}
```

I'm new to Angular, so this might be something stupid. And, I can't post this JSON as a body because the API endpoint only accepts it as a parameter. I'd highly appreciate any help or guide towards proper blog/tutorial.

Comment: put your `options` object into `http.post` call as a second parameter, instead of `null`

Comment: @deezg If I'm not wrong, it would then send JSON as the body of the request instead of a parameter, right?

Comment: try `params: {'id': JSON.stringify(options)}`

Comment: right. sorry, i missread your question. now i see you must post but with url params. then yes, you need to send json as string. / @Reactgular just showed a way

Comment: @Beevk can you show your api signature? it cannot get anything else than string in url parameters. so, its rather unclear what "valid json" means in context of url parameter.

Comment: @Reactgular btw, one might want to add `encodeURIComponent` after `JSON.stringify`, right?

Comment: I tried `params: {'id': JSON.stringify(options)}` but the server gave me a 405 (method not allowed) error. It seems to be working fine in postman.

Comment: @deezg I think HttpClient applies encoding for you.

Comment: @Reactgular might be, not sure. didn't need it for a while.

Comment: @Beevk can you show your API method full signature/definition? because this way we might be facing several problems, client & server wise.